# Why does Angular2 component need mandatory @Inject for dependency injection

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Dependency injection in my component doesn't work by default
I have to add the @Inject decorator explicitly

My application consists from multiple files.

**main ts**:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.module.ts**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './appcomponent/app.component';
import { PostComponent } from './postcomponent/post.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        PostComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    providers: [MyService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**appcomponent/app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],   
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

**postcomponent/post.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from "../my.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-post',
    templateUrl: './post.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./post.component.css']
})
export class PostComponent {
    constructor(private service: MyService) {        
    }
}
```

**my.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class MyService {   
    send(message: string): void {
        alert(message);
    }
}
```

**ts.config.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true, // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17863. Remove this if you upgrade to a fixed version of Angular.
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angulartest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

It throws the exception

> bundle.js:sourcemap:31848 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters
>   for PostComponent: (?).

I have to use

```
constructor(@Inject(MyService) private service: MyService) {
```

instead of

```
constructor(private service: MyService) {
```

why?

I've read in https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html
that angular adds metadata for dependency injection automatically if class has a decorator.
But my PostComponent class has a decorator @Component.

Comment: The angular configuration is correct, the dependency should be injected. Maybe is related to the ts configuration. Could you add your package.json?

Comment: {
     "name": "angulartest",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "",
     "main": "index.js",
     "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
     },
     "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
   }

Comment: I don't know why my packages are not added to package.json

Comment: update your question, dont add them in comments

Comment: I afraid I cannot do it. I don't see a button/link Edit near my question.

Comment: I found link Edit. and I've updated